# How can I change the view from a view with animation

Tags: ios, animation, view

I know there are two ways,

1. [self.navigationController pushViewController:siteViewController animated:YES];
2. [self presentModalViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];

However, those ways are too boring. So, what can I do to have more animation? I should add a view from a window? Any example about this?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605959/implement-custom-animation-to-present-modal-view-from-specified-view-on-ipad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these similar questions:

- [how to implement an iPhone view transition animation with both flipping and scaling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755492/how-to-implement-an-iphone-view-transition-animation-with-both-flipping-and-scal)
- [Custom transition between two UIViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511514/custom-transition-between-two-uiviews/8931492#8931492)
- [Animating View Transitions with Core Animation](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/220092-animating-view-transitions-with-core-animation-problems-with-basiccocoaanimations-sample.html)

Also, here is a very cool library allowing for easy 3D view transitions: http://maniacdev.com/2011/08/open-source-3d-view-transitions-library-including-cloth-and-flip-style-transitions/

--------------UPDATE--------------

This is also a really neat transitions library called MPFoldTransition that allows for transitions like this:

[image]

You can download it [here](https://github.com/mpospese/MPFoldTransition).

Hope this helps!